# Getting error firebase module not called while uploading image to firestore databse

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am trying to upload a picture to firestore storage using an async function. I have added the configuration files from the firebase in the project. I am using expo workflow for my project and and I am using expo image picker to get images from the device.

```
const AddPictures = () => {

  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);
  const [transferred, setTransferred] = useState(0);

  const imagePicker = async () => {
    let permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
      alert("Permission to access camera roll is required!");
      return;
    }

    let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();
    if (pickerResult.cancelled === true) {
      return;
    }
    const source = { uri: pickerResult.uri }
    console.log(source)
    setSelectedImage(source)
  }

  

  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const { uri } = selectedImage;
    const filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    console.log(filename)
    
    setUploading(true);
  
    
    try {
      await storage().ref(filename).putFile(uploadUri);

      setUploading(false);
      Alert.alert(
        'Photo uploaded!',
        'Your photo has been uploaded to Firebase Cloud Storage!'
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    
    setSelectedImage(null);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.selectButton} onPress={imagePicker}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Pick an image</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        {selectedImage !== null ? (
          <Image source={{ uri: selectedImage.uri }} style={styles.imageBox} />
        ) : null}
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.uploadButton} onPress={uploadImage}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Upload image</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

This is the error I am getting on the calling the uploadImage fucntion.

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Where is the `storage()` function imported from? Also can you share the file where you've initialized Firebase?

Comment: I am importing the storage package from 
"import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';".
And its present in pacakge.js as well :
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.9.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^14.9.1",